# What is the correct way of using extendData in dcc.Graph?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I am trying to limit the number of points that are graphed by the dcc.Graph figure with the following code:

```
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_core_components as dcc
import numpy as np

from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State

# Example data (a circle).
resolution = 1000
t = np.linspace(0, np.pi * 2, resolution)
x, y = np.cos(t), np.sin(t)
# Example app.
figure = dict(data=[{'x': [], 'y': []}])
app = dash.Dash(__name__, update_title=None)  # remove "Updating..." from title
app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Graph(id='graph', figure=dict(figure)), dcc.Interval(id="interval", interval=10),
    dcc.Store(id='store', data=dict(x=x, y=y, resolution=resolution)),
])
app.clientside_callback(
    """
    function (n_intervals, data) {
        return [{x: [data.x], y: [data.y]}, [0], 10]
    }
    """,
    [Output('graph', 'extendData')],
    [Input('interval', 'n_intervals')], 
    [State('store', 'data')]
)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server()
```

What I would expect, that when I use `return [{x: [data.x], y: [data.y]}, [0], 10]`, the 10 at the end limits the number of points on the graph to 10. Although, when I run the sample code, a full circle is drawn. According to the documentation, extendData requires the following return:

> extendData (list | dict; optional): Data that should be appended to
> existing traces. Has the form [updateData, traceIndices, maxPoints],
> where updateData is an object containing the data to extend,
> traceIndices (optional) is an array of trace indices that should be
> extended, and maxPoints (optional) is either an integer defining the
> maximum number of points allowed or an object with key:value pairs
> matching updateData Reference the Plotly.extendTraces API for full
> usage:
> https://plotly.com/javascript/plotlyjs-function-reference/#plotlyextendtraces

Am I misunderstanding the use of the maxPoints parameter, or am I implementing it wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is quite subtle and it took me a while to figure it out...

In your callback decorator:

```py
app.clientside_callback(
    """
    function (n_intervals, data) {
        return [{x: [data.x], y: [data.y]}, [0], 10]
    }
    """,
    [Output('graph', 'extendData')],
    [Input('interval', 'n_intervals')], 
    [State('store', 'data')]
)
```

Since `Output` is in a list, your return should also be a list with `extendData` as single element. However you are returning the "unpacked" `extendedData`, so Dash ignores the two other elements and send just `updateData={x: [data.x], y: [data.y]}`.

To fix it, just use `Output('graph', 'extendData')` not in a list.

Comment: Good catch! Thank you!